# Need hardware recommendation for a new modem/router to replace apparently unsuitable hardware

Tags: networking, router

Specifically the unit needs to support [PPPoA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPPoA), which is the point at which my older [WRT54G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linksys_WRT54G_series) (sadly, revision 7, termed 'not possible' by [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/dd-wrt/hardware.html)) is (or seems) unusable.

Essentially, the network would be used to share regular browsing and perhaps occasional media; limited-to-no internet-gaming, so while gigabit ethernet would be nice, it's not *essential* that the hardware support it.

Perhaps as a tangent, with the WRT54G, I have an [ADSL2MUE](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/ADSL2MUE) router, which is itself capable of PPPoA; is there any way of connecting the two devices together while having the modem control/handle the connection? The set-up instructions I followed -that came with the devices- suggest that the router takes (and has to take) control of everything, which is a bit of a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Troggy; I should've had the sense to use those words to start with =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll look at the documentation on the modem/router, but you should be able to set it up such that the modem is plugged into the wall, the "WAN" ethernet port on the WRT is plugged into the modem, and your internal network is plugged into the WRT's switch.

I had to do something similar when I was on DSL; the LEC insisted that I had to use their modem, and that was the only way it worked.  The subnetting was a bit wacky, but it can be made to work.

**Edit**:  Leave it to me to always make more work for myself.  [This](http://forums.linksys.com/linksys/board/message?board.id=Wireless_Routers&message.id=26177) is a post on the Linksys forum explaining how to set up precisely what you're asking about, without doing the subnetting weirdness that I put myself through.

Comment: You, sir, may well be a genius (albeit perhaps masochistic...) =)

Comment: Although, having read the guide...the problem is that the WRT seems to insist/demand upon controlling the modem, and the WRT cannot deal with PPPoA (which my ISP requires/uses). The guide you link to, seems focused on extending the network without creating a subnet; which is interesting, but not the problem I have. Or have I misread? O.o

Comment: Gah! I hate the comment system.
Okay; in principle, that guide is removing the WRT's layer 3 services from the equation, and turning it into a glorified switch/WAP.
What I did in my setup had the modem between the outside and a 192.168.1.0/24 subnet on its internal port.  The WRT's external (Internet/WAN) port was set to a 192.168.1.0/24 address, while its internal ports defined the 192.168.2.0/24; all internal clients were on 192.168.2.0/24.

Comment: Make sure that you have the WRT set to not try any authentication; in whichever option you choose, you want it to simply be a switch or dumb router; the WRT should have an "authentication mode" option or something like that.  I'll dig my WRT out tonight and try to amplify further.

Comment: Thanks =) sorry it took so long to remember I had a question here...*blush*...